# Display yesterday's last post's Custom field from Unique terms of one Taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy, terms, date

I have problem in my first theme design, and I think you can help me easily!(I searched my problem several times in Google and WordPress codex but I cant find exactly that I want!!)

I want to displaying my "**yesterday**'s last post's Custom filed, from Unique terms of one Taxonomies" in a cell of table!

In another cell I want to display "last post's Custom filed, from Unique terms of one Taxonomies"

I use this code:

```
<?php
/**
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Default_Theme
*/
    $yesterday = strtotime("-1 day");
    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", $yesterday);
    $today = date("Y-m-d");
$querystr = "SELECT wposts.*
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
    AND wposts.post_date >= '$yesterday'
    AND wposts.post_date <= '$today'
    AND wposts.post_type = 'MY-CUSTOM-POST-NAME'
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date ASC;";
$posts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
get_header();
?>
<div  id="content" role="main">
<?php 

if($posts) {
    foreach($posts AS $post) setup_postdata($post);
    {
        ?>
<div id="post-<?php  the_ID(); ?>">
<div> <?php  echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'MY-CUSTOM-FIELD',TRUE) ?></div>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
<?php  } else { ?>
<h2>Not Found</h2>
<p>Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
<?php  get_search_form(); ?>
<?php  } ?>
</div>
<?php  get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

but this code display my "last Custom filed from **ALL terms** of one Taxonomies!"

Please Help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood everything correct:

- display a specific custom field
- from a custom post-type post
- assigned to a specific term in a custom taxonomy
- for todays and yesterdays latest entry

I can't solve this task improving your SQL-statement, but you can try the following function using standard WordPress stuff:

```
function show_latest48h_post_cf_in_term( $cpt, $tax, $term_slug, $cf ) {        
                    /* vars */
        /******************************************************/
        $output = '';
        $today_latest = '';
        $yesterday_latest = '';
        $timestamp = current_time( 'timestamp' );
        $today = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', $timestamp);
        $yesterday = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime('-1 day', $timestamp));
        $today_ar = date_parse($today);
        $yesterday_ar = date_parse($yesterday);

        /* today */
        /******************************************************/                 
        // args
        $args_today = array(
            'post_type' => $cpt,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => $tax,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term_slug
                )
            ),
            'year' => $today_ar["year"],
            'monthnum' => $today_ar["month"],
            'day' => $today_ar["day"],
            'meta_key' => $cf,
            'posts_per_page'  => 1
        );
        // get today post
        $today_query = get_posts($args_today);        
        if ($today_query) {                
                $today_latest .= '<p>' . $today . ': ' . get_post_meta( $today_query[0]->ID, $cf, true) . '</p>';                    
        }

        /* yesterday */
        /******************************************************/                 
        // args
        $args_yesterday = array(
            'post_type' => $cpt,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                        'taxonomy' => $tax,
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $term_slug
                )
            ),
            'year' => $yesterday_ar["year"],
            'monthnum' => $yesterday_ar["month"],
            'day' => $yesterday_ar["day"],
            'meta_key' => $cf,
            'posts_per_page'  => 1
        );
        // get yesterday post
        $yesterday_query = get_posts($args_yesterday);        
        if ($yesterday_query) {
            $yesterday_latest .= '<p>' . $yesterday . ': ' . get_post_meta( $yesterday_query[0]->ID, $cf, true) . '</p>';                    
        }

        /* output */
        /******************************************************/            
        if ($today_query || $yesterday_query) {
            $output = $today_latest . $yesterday_latest;
        } else {
            $output = 'Nothing found';
        }
        echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rfrq i think this code is helping me but: Please let me know where can i input my cpt, tax, term_slug & cf in this code! because i replaced $cpt with my custom post type name and $tax... but nothing happened.(blank page)?? my cpt=portfolio / tax=web / term_slug=php / cf = year ....

Comment: You have to copy the whole function as it is into your themes `functions.php` . Then call `show_latest48h_post_cf_in_term( $cpt, $tax, $term_slug, $cf )` anywhere in your theme. In your case `show_latest48h_post_cf_in_term( 'portfolio', 'web', 'php', 'year' )` should work.

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much its working now ;) BUT dear @rfrq this code i worked but doesn't show my current local time its work with UTC time!

Comment: Now the function uses WordPress' `current_time()` function which relates to your blog settings. I also improved speed +120-160% by using `get_posts` instead of `WP_Query`. I tried to find a solution which takes care of the visitors timezone and experimented a lot but I always got UTC.

Comment: dear @rfrq i want show last post's date&time (local time/(GMT + 4:30)) publish date

Comment: `$today_query[0]` and `$yesterday_query[0]` both contain the following data: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post . You can use `$today_query[0]->post_date` and `$yesterday_query[0]->post_date`

Comment: hello again. please help me again : i have another page and i want show just "last post's Custom field from Unique terms of one Taxonomies" not today or yesterday just latest Custom field in one cell of table. and do this for all my Taxonomies and put all in cell in table! i hope you can answer this correct like my previous question ;)

Answer (score 0):

First, use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) rather than your own SQL.

I think this is what you want:

```
$yesterday = strtotime("-1 day");
$yesterday = date("Y-m-d", $yesterday);
$yesterday = explode('-',$yesterday);
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'MY-CUSTOM-POST-NAME',
  'year' => $yesterday[0],
  'monthnum' => $yesterday[1],
  'day' => $yesterday[2],
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'people',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'bob'
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

## Some explanation:

If what you want is posts from "yesterday" you don't really need to check for posts between today and yesterday, you just ask for posts from yesterday.

When you say you want "from Unique terms of one Taxonomies", I really don't know what you mean but I *think* that you mean you want posts from some particular term or terms from some particular taxonomy, hence the `tax_query`.